# Average row values until today

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image]

I would like to Average the column up to todays date. For example in the picture above it`s the 16th of October and I would like to average all values up to the 16th of October.

I tried the following:

```
=AVERAGEIF($C$3:$Z$3;<=$B$1;$C$4:$Z$4)
```

However, I only get `#ERROR!` back. Below you can find the above spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xp05kTCP8MJG4NAPJl1lKw6z4NzOQZJydqe1zYXSzoc/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in B4 and copy down:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER($C$4:$Z$4;$C3:$Z3<=$B$1))
```